# Office add-in not working if manifest contains & (ampersand)

Tags: xml, office-js

In my Word add-in manifest, I tried to include several & (ampersand) characters, in places such as

```
<ProviderName>Whatever &amp; sons</ProviderName>
<DisplayName DefaultValue="Whatever &amp; sons add-in" />
```

I tried both codes that I found on the internet, namely `&amp;` and `&#38;`.

With both, my XML is valid in my editor and the add-in works in Word Client.

BUT, when I try to load the add-in in Word Online, the add-in does not load at all and gives me an error pop-up saying "Sorry, something went wrong. Could you please try that again ?"
Plus, I get an error message only in Edge, where I get the following :

```
XML5608: Expecting semicolon
```

As soon as I remove my `&amp;`, the add-in works perfectly.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send 2 ampersands.

Try:

```
&#38;&#38;
```

That should work.

Comment: Not working ! 'Cause in XML, you can't set a property with "&&", and "&amp;&amp;" is parsed correctly, but that puts me back in the same Office problem as described above ! :)

Comment: lol i meant t times the escape notation :) check my answer again.

Comment: This is a _fantastic_ tidbit. This should be marked correct. My information is outdated, `<ProviderName>Whatever &#38;&#38; sons</ProviderName>` worked like a charm.

Comment: Well, this works for the <ProviderName> tag, but not in the other tags where I need it, like <DisplayName DefaultValue="Whatever &#38;&#38; sons"></DisplayName>.
In fact, it works for the content of a tag, but for the value of a tag property !
So I am marking this as an answer, because it is one ; but note that it does not work entirely.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [long-standing issue with ampersands](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/issues/279) in the manifest. I'm afraid the only workaround at the moment is to use `and` instead of `&`, `&amp;`, or `&#38`.

```
<ProviderName>Whatever and sons</ProviderName>
<DisplayName DefaultValue="Whatever and sons add-in" />
```

Comment: Ok, noted. All in all, I feel better,I feared I was missing something obvious out ! ;-)

Comment: Marius: try my answer and let me know how it goes.